# How to catch files downloaded by a web app

Tags: firefox, proxy, wget

In firefox, when one open the developer tools and a web page, he can see, in the network tab, a list of https requests and responses. Most of them are files (.html, .js, .css, .png) with an associated MIME.

I'm looking for a way to properly download these files in a dedicated folder... (The page being dynamic, it regularly update some of them)

Up to now, I played a bit and:

- failed with wget and python scripts, because the pages I want to scan are located behind a login.
- failed with my first attempt with wireshark, because is was TLS encrypted (I plan to try [this](https://redflagsecurity.net/2019/03/10/decrypting-tls-wireshark/), but wireshark is nonetheless a bit overkill).
- looked for a firefox extension but I found dozens to clear the cache, none to save it...

What would you recommend for the job ? The solution could be based on scripts, "proxy-like" systems or firefox extensions or anything else valid.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use Save As on the page, or is your problem more complex than that?

Comment: It doesn't work well, the page is dynamic, and downloads a new image every second or so, and if I save the page I lose this. But in the network tab, I clearly see the new requests and the news responses